# how to display only the child categories using get_categories

Tags: php, wordpress

> CATEGORY 1
>   - 2nd level category
>     -- 3rd level category
>       --- 4th level category
>   - 2nd level category
>     -- 3rd level category
>       --- 4th level category
>   - 2nd level category
>     -- 3rd level category
>       --- 4th level category

How can I show only the 4th level categories in a list with `show_count=1` using `get_categories`?

well, as of now im using this code I got from other source

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories('child_of=2796&hide_empty=0&taxonomy=product_cat&title_li=red&depth=3&show_count=1'); ?>
</ul>
```

and it displays this

```
Wine
  red
    Barbera (7)
        Barbera (7)  <-  last category
    Bonarda (2)
        Bonarda (2)  <-  last category
    Bordeaux Blend (15)
        Cabernet Franc (6)  <-  last category
        Cabernet Sauvignon (14)  <-  last category
        Merlot (15)  <-  last category
        Petit Verdot (3)  <-  last category
    Cabernet Franc (4)
        Cabernet Franc (4)  <-  last category
    Cabernet Sauvignon (29)
        Cabernet Sauvignon (29)  <-  last category
```

I need it to display only a list of all the last category

```
    Barbera (7)
    Bonarda (2)
    Cabernet Franc (6)
    Cabernet Sauvignon (14)
    Merlot (15)
    Petit Verdot (3)
    Cabernet Franc (4)
    Cabernet Sauvignon (29)
```

sorry for making a confusion, i am not good at this :-(

Comment: What is it displaying now? All the posts from all the categories?

Comment: not the post, but the last category. I have 4 levels of category, I need the 4th category to display. :-)

Comment: please help, anybody...

Answer (score 1):

Can you please explain yourself a bit more? show_count=1 and your custom function get_categories() doesn't mean a thing to me. Please add your script code.

At first glance I'd say you'd best stick all categories in an array. Eg:

```
$categories = array(
"level1" => array(1 => "level 1.1", 2 => "level 1.2"),
"level2" => array(1 => "level 2.1", 2 => "level 2.2", ...)
...
);
```

next you can get the 4th level by addressing it as $categories[x][4] (with x = the number of the category you want to address)

Comment: I have edited My question for clear understand. I hope I made it clearer

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found a solution for you!

Your wp_list_categories should be this:

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=name&include=3,5,9,16'); ?> 
</ul>
```

Where it orders your categories by name and it only includes certain categories by their ID.
So from the above it will only list categories with ID's: 3,5,9 and 16

You can also `exclude` categories if it takes longer to write out the include. So lets say you have more `include` ID's than `exclude`, then use `&exclude=6,11`. Where it will exclude categories with ID's: 6 and 11.

I don't think there's any simpler solution to this unless you write a plugin for it!

You can find out more what you can do with it reading this http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Include_or_Exclude_Categories